# Haskell save recursive steps into a list

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus

I'm working on Haskell lambda calculus interpreter. I have a method which reduces expression to it's normal form.

```
type Var = String

data Term =
    Variable Var
  | Lambda   Var  Term
  | Apply    Term Term
  deriving Show

normal :: Term -> Term
normal (Variable index)      = Variable index
normal (Lambda var body)       = Lambda var (normal body)
normal (Apply left right) = case normal left of
    Lambda var body  -> normal (substitute var (normal right) body)
    otherwise -> Apply (normal left) (normal right)
```

How can I save the steps taken into a collection?

My normal function outputs this:
`\a. \b. a (a (a (a b)))`
and my goal would be to get all the steps as:

```
(\f. \x. f (f x)) (\f. \x. f (f x)),
\a. (\f. \x. f (f x)) ((\f. \x. f (f x)) a),
\a. \b. (\f. \x. f (f x)) a ((\f. \x. f (f x)) a b),
\a. \b. (\b. a (a b)) ((\f. \x. f (f x)) a b),
\a. \b. a (a ((\f. \x. f (f x)) a b)),
\a. \b. a (a ((\b. a (a b)) b)),
\a. \b. a (a (a (a b)))]
```

I've tried encapsulating the normal method into lists as follows:

```
normal :: Term -> [Term]
normal (Variable index)      = Variable index
normal (Lambda var body)       = term: [Lambda var (normal body)]
normal (Apply left right) = case normal left of
    Lambda var body  -> normal (substitute var (normal right) body)
    otherwise -> Apply (normal left) (normal right)
```

But that doesn't seem to be the right approach.

Comment: Could you include the full `Terms` in your input and expected output?

Comment: It looks like the most Haskell-y way would be creating some optics for Terms. Each normalisation step would get a whole Term and some lens, and output an optional new Term and a list of new lenses to try. If you get a new Term, it means a single normalisation step was done and you need to add the old term to the log and continue with the new one. If you get some lenses, add them to the existing list. At each step you take the first lens from the list and run it. If you have an empty list of lenses, you are done. Note I don't necessarily know what I'm talking about, season with salt to taste.

Comment: @bwroga not sure if I understand what do you mean. Like example of a term?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I'm probably misunderstanding your idea. But isn't it enough that everytime the last pattern is matched I'm normalising therefore it should be just enough to encorporate the list save step into the code? The normal function seems to be working correctly therefore I would just need to save the step everytime it plans to recurse, wouldn't that work?

Comment: It would be nice if you included your definition for `substitute`. I believe you that it works and isn't the focus of the question, but when working on an answer it's nice to be able to test that it produces the right results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, but there's just a lot more you need to do.  Remember, if you change the type of your function from `Term -> Term` to `Term -> [Term]`, then you need to make sure that for any input `Term`, the function produces an output `[Term]`.  However, in your new implementation of `normal`, you only made the change for one case (and in doing so, you made up some new value called `term` — not sure why you did that).

So, let's think through the *whole* problem.  What is the list of `Term` that should be produced by `normal` when the input is `Variable index`?  Well, there's no work to do, so it should probably be a singleton list:

```hs
normal' (Variable index) = [Variable index]
```

How about for `Lambda var body`?  You wrote `term: [Lambda var (normal' body)]`, but this doesn't make any sense.  Remember that `normal' body` is now producing a list, but `Lambda` can't take a list of terms as its body argument.  And what is this `term` value you're trying to cons onto your singleton list?

Calling `normal' body` is a great idea.  This produces a list of `Term`s, which represent partial normalizations of the body.  But, we want to produce partial normalizations of the *lambda*, not just the body.  So, we need to modify each element in the list, converting it from a body to a lamdba:

```hs
normal' (Lambda var body) = Lambda var <$> normal' body
```

Hooray!  (Note that since we're not doing any actual normalization in this step, we don't need to increase the length of the list.)

(For the sake of coding convenience, for the final case, we will construct the list of partial terms in reverse order.  We can always reverse it later.)

The last case is the hardest, but it follows the same principles.  We begin by recognizing that the recursive calls `normal' left` and `normal' right` will return *lists* of results rather than simply the final term:

```hs
normal' (Apply left right) =
  let lefts  = normal' left
      rights = normal' right
```

One question this raises is: Which evaluation steps do we take first?  Let's choose to evaluate `left` first.  This means that all of the evaluation steps for `left` must be paired with the original `right`, and all of the evaluation steps for `right` must be paired with the most evaluated `left`.

```hs
normal' (Apply left right) =
  let lefts  = normal' left
      rights = normal' right
      lefts'  = flip Apply right <$> lefts
      rights' = Apply (head lefts) <$> init rights
      evalSoFar = rights' + lefts'
```

Note the use of `init rights` at the end — since the last element of `rights` should be equal to `right` and we already have a value with the head of `lefts` and the last element of `rights` in `lefts'`, we omit the last element of of `rights` when building `rights'`.

From here, all we need to do is actually perform our substitution (assuming that `head lefts` is indeed a `Lambda` expression) and concatenate our `evalSoFar` list to what it produces:

```hs
normal' (Apply left right) =
  let lefts  = normal' left
      rights = normal' right
      lefts'  = flip Apply right <$> lefts
      rights' = Apply (head lefts) <$> init rights
      evalSoFar = rights' ++ lefts'
  in case (lefts, rights) of
    (Lambda var body : _, right' : _) -> normal' (substitute var right' body) ++ evalSoFar
    _ -> evalSoFar
```

Remember that this produces the list backwards, so we can define `normal` as follows:

```hs
normal :: Term -> [Term]
normal = reverse . normal'
```

---

It's hard for me to test this exactly considering you didn't provide a definition of `substitute`, but I'm pretty sure it should do what you want.

That said, I will note that the resulting evaluation steps I get from evaluating your sample term are *not* the same as those given in the question.  Specifically, your second evaluation step, going from

```
\a. (\f. \x. f (f x)) ((\f. \x. f (f x)) a),
\a. \b. (\f. \x. f (f x)) a ((\f. \x. f (f x)) a b),
```

seems wrong based on your implementation.  Note that here you're performing a substitution before fully evaluating the argument.  If you run the code in this answer, you'll see that the result you get does *not* perform this step but rather fully evaluates the function argument (that is, `((\f. \x. f (f x)) a)`) before substituting.

Comment: Thank you the answer. I think I'm still missing something here. Especially the first point in the last section you've pointed out that normal' right and normal' left now return list of terms. In the reforming I was thinking to just take the last element out of the list since, that should be the latest normalization, however that doesn't seems to be working. Was that the thing you had in mind or am I missing something?

Comment: If you just take the last element of the list, then you'll never end up returning any of the other partway steps of normalization.  Consider the case for `Lambda var body` — we don't just take the last element of the list produced by `normal' body`.  Of course, you _need_ that last element to continue the normalizing process, but you must not ignore the other elements.

Comment: Quick tip: It may be easier to write if you let `normal'` produce the list in _reverse order_.  Then, you're more interested in the head of the list (which you can grab via pattern matching) than the tail.  If you write it so the list is produced forwards, then you may want to ignore the stub I proposed and instead write, e.g. `let lefts = normal' left; rights = normal' right` and then pattern match on `last lefts` to see if you have a `Lambda` in the function position.

Comment: I seem to be getting nowhere with the approach, I've tried to do the list backwards, but it seems like I'm at the dead end. Could you please elaborate a bit on the answer you've made?

Comment: I updated my answer to include some code that produces the (reversed) evaluation steps for the `Apply` case.

Comment: How would one go about saving the steps into the evalSoFar? Should this happen in the `normal' (Apply left right)` case or elsewhere? I still seem to be missing something.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking.  `evalSoFar` is defined as the concatenation of `rights'` and `lefts'`, meaning that it already _is_ all of the evaluation steps needed to normalize `left` and `right`.

Comment: Sorry If I'm not clear I was reffering to : "From here, all we need to do is actually perform our substitution (assuming that head lefts is indeed a Lambda expression) and concatenate our evalSoFar list to what it produces." don't really know how to proceed here.

Comment: Would you mind providing the complete solution to the problem? I seem to be not getting anywhere after days of trying/

Comment: I added the last couple lines.  Hopefully this works for you, but I'd also be curious to see what you tried for those last few lines (or if you could describe a little more _why_ you're confused).  It would help me answer questions better in the future.

Comment: I think the complexity of the problem is beyond my knowledge, which makes understanding the solution harder and probably that is the reason why I'm being confused so much.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're putting the cart before the horse. `normal` repeatedly reduces a term until it cannot be reduced any more. Where, then, is the function that actually reduces a term *once*?

```
reduce :: Term -> Maybe Term -- returns Nothing if no reduction
reduce (Variable _) = Nothing -- variables don't reduce
reduce (Lambda v b) = Lambda v <$> reduce b -- an abstraction reduces as its body does
reduce (Apply (Lambda v b) x) = Just $ substitute v x b -- actual meaning of reduction
reduce (Apply f x) = flip Apply x <$> reduce f <|> Apply f <$> reduce x -- try to reduce f, else try x
```

Then

```
normal :: Term -> [Term]
normal x = x : maybe [] normal (reduce x)
```

Or, to be slightly more accurate

```
import Data.List.NonEmpty as NE
normal :: Term -> NonEmpty Term
normal = NE.unfoldr $ (,) <*> reduce
```

---

Note that this definition of `reduce` also corrects a bug in your original `normal`. There are terms which have normal forms that your `normal` fails to evaluate. Consider the term

```
(\x y. y) ((\x. x x) (\x. x x)) -- (const id) omega
```

This normalizes to `\y. y`. Depending on how `substitute` is implemented, your `normal` might succeed or fail to normalize this term. If it succeeds, it will have been saved by laziness. A hypothetical "stepping" version of your `normal`, which normalizes arguments before substitution, would definitely fail to normalize this.

Refraining from reducing the argument before substitution guarantees you will find the normal form of any term, if a normal form exists. You can restore the eager behavior with

```
eagerReduce t@(Apply f@(Lambda v b) x) = Apply f <$> eagerReduce x <|> Just (substitute v x b)
-- other equations...
eagerNormal = NE.unfoldr $ (,) <*> eagerReduce
```

As promised, `eagerNormal` produces an infinite list on my example term and never finds the normal form.

Comment: Nice answer!  One note though -- despite your `<|> Apply f <$> reduce x` in the last reduce case, that code will only ever execute if the `f` term of the `Apply` is _not_ a `Lambda`.  However, the semantics of the original normalization reduces the `x` part fully before substitution.  I think in the line where you substitute, you need to assure that `x` is "fully reduced" (i.e., either a `Variable` or a `Lambda`)

Comment: @DDub I think adding `Apply (Lambda v b) <$> reduce x <|>` to the third equation of `reduce` should do that. Though, I would consider it a *bug* in the original implementation to try to normalize the argument first, because it fails to normalize some terms that do have a normal form.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this requires "re-implementation" of the original normal method.  Is there a way to merge yours reduce and normal into one function? with the signature as `normal :: Term -> [Term]` ?

Comment: The code doesn't seem to be working `Variable not in scope:
        (<|>) :: Maybe Term -> Maybe Term -> Maybe Term
    * Perhaps you meant one of these:
        `<>' (imported from Prelude), `<*>' (imported from Prelude),
        `<$>' (imported from Prelude)`

Comment: @gaming4mining I would consider directly writing `normal :: Term -> [Term]` to be a bad thing in itself; it is too messy. As for `(<|>)`, [import it!](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--124--62-).

Answer (score 1):

When I think "I want a computation to produce extra information as it progresses", I say: "Why should I implement this by hand, when Writer is right there?" Writer is the way to produce a pair when you're mostly only interested in one half of the pair, and the other half is some structure you just append to like a log.

You didn't provide `substitute`, and I didn't want to implement it, so I wrote my own simple language to reduce. This also leaves you the exercise of applying the same technique to your language.

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Writer.Lazy (Writer, runWriter, tell, censor)

data Sum = Number Int
         | Sum :+ Sum

instance Show Sum where
  show (Number n) = show n
  show (x :+ y) = "(" ++ show x ++ " + " ++ show y ++ ")"
```

The key Writer functions we'll need to implement this, in addition to the usual Applicative/Monad combinators, are [`tell`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-Lazy.html#v:tell) and [`censor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-Lazy.html#v:censor). `tell` is pretty boring: it just says "append this to the log". `censor` is interesting: it runs another Writer and returns that Writer's output, but it also modifies the log produced by that Writer.

The idea is to use `tell` to log the term every time we make a reduction, and to use `censor` to ensure that logged sub-terms are properly placed into the context of the overall computation.

```
normalize :: Sum -> Writer [Sum] Sum
normalize root = tell [root] *> go root
  where go n@(Number _) = pure n
        go ((Number left) :+ (Number right)) =
          let sum = (Number (left + right))
          in tell [sum] *> pure sum
        go (left :+ right) = do
          left' <- censor (map (:+ right)) (go left)
          right' <- censor (map (left' :+)) (go right)
          go $ left' :+ right'
```

To that end, note that our only `tell` (other than at the root, to show the original expression) is in the case where both operands are already reduced, so that we can do some simplification. In the non-reduced case, we simply normalize both operands, placing any logs produced into the broader context. Your language has different reduction steps, of course; as long as you make sure to log something exactly when you directly simplify something, you won't wind up with duplicate or missing steps. I think the only reduction you ever do is a substitution, so that should be simple enough.

Observe that this produces a desirable result:

```
main = print . runWriter . normalize $
  (Number 1 :+ Number 2) :+ (Number 3 :+ (Number 4 :+ Number 5))

$ runghc tmp.hs
(15,[((1 + 2) + (3 + (4 + 5))),(3 + (3 + (4 + 5))),(3 + (3 + 9)),(3 + 12),15])
```

Here the returned pair contains the expected result (`Number 15`) on the left, and the set of reductions applied on the right, in the order they were done.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, however, to me It looks like that would require a change of the method signature, which is unfortunately not an option :(.

Comment: You never need to change the method signature for implementation details. You can just have an outer facade with the required signature delegate to an inner function with a different signature. `normalize = execWriter [] . normalize'` or similar.